# one model belongs to two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, belongs-to

I know similar questions have been asked before, but can't find one that's close enough to what I need for me to learn how to do this.

I have 3 models: wedding, reception, and attendee

The idea is that a user will be able to go to the wedding's event page where it will have some info, an address, and a list of receptions. The user will be able to select what receptions they're going to be at, insert their name and address, and then be inserted into the database as an attendee for that wedding.

What I am having the most trouble with is wrapping my head around the idea of having one model belong to two other models. Namely the reception model belonging to both the wedding model and the attendee model.

How can I go about doing this?

This is my schema:

```
create_table "attendees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.string   "address",    limit: 255
    t.integer  "people",     limit: 4
    t.string   "receptions", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",         limit: 255
    t.string   "slug",         limit: 255
    t.text     "description",  limit: 65535
    t.string   "address",      limit: 255
    t.float    "latitude",     limit: 24
    t.float    "longitude",    limit: 24
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.boolean  "saved",        limit: 1,     default: false
    t.integer  "actable_id",   limit: 4
    t.string   "actable_type", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
  end

  create_table "receptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address",    limit: 255
    t.float    "latitude",   limit: 24
    t.float    "longitude",  limit: 24
    t.integer  "wedding_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

add_index "receptions", ["wedding_id"], name: "fk_rails_40f4f8c049", using: :btree

create_table "weddings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "brides_name", limit: 255
    t.string   "grooms_name", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "receptions", "weddings"
```

Oh, I also have an event's table. I am using the ActiveRecord::ActsAs gem to make weddings act as Events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reception` model definitely doesn't `belong_to` the `Attendee` model.

The relationship between Receptions and Attendees will be either a has_many, or a 'has_many through' relationship. It's worth reading through the [full doco](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on assocations.

You mention:

> The idea is that a user will be able to go to the wedding's event page
>   where it will have some info, an address, and a list of receptions.
>   The user will be able to select what receptions they're going to be
>   at, insert their name and address, and then be inserted into the
>   database as an attendee for that wedding.

Just to clarify we're on the right page, is it true that a single wedding will have multiple receptions? And that an individual guest can select which of those multiple receptions they're going to attend? So a guest may attend 2 out of 3 receptions, for a single wedding? And what about the wedding itself? Can guests attend some of the receptions but not the related wedding? Or if they're attending any of the receptions, is it automatically assumed they'll be attending the wedding, too?

And how do you determine if a particular person is in fact invited to a wedding? Can I browse your site and just list myself as an attendee for several receptions, uninvited?

Something seems off in the way you've described the data model - at least, the data structure you've described doesn't match weddings we're all used to. You may well have a valid reason for this. If so, update your question with a bit more background info on the underlying problem you're trying to solve, and the real-life situations  you're trying to model. It'll allow people to help you more easily.

## Update: this should work

```
# wedding.rb
has_many :receptions

# reception.rb
belongs_to :wedding
has_many :attendees, through: :reception_attendees

# attendee.rb
belongs_to :wedding
has_many :receptions, through: :reception_attendees

# reception_attendee.rb
belongs_to :reception
belongs_to :attendee
```

So you'll need a "has many through" relationship between attendees and receptions. That'll mean that you'll need a new model and database table, `reception_attendees`, which will be a links table between receptions and attendees.

Comment: to start with people are only going to be able to RSVP for a reception because that's what I'm in need of right now. A little further down the line I'll allow people to RSVP for the wedding as well, but it's not necessary in my case. You have it right though. A wedding will have multiple receptions and a user will be able to select one or multiple to attend.

Comment: How do you identify users? What's to stop me RSVPing for some random person's reception?

Comment: I am still thinking that one out. My idea is that the user that creates the event will be able to share a special link with those they want to invite. At least initially, until I can get some email verification in there

Comment: And is it important in any way to identify users/guests between weddings? For example, if Bob Smith is a guest at Fred's wedding, and also at Mark's wedding, is it important to identify that it is in fact the same Bob Smith going to both weddings? Or does that not matter?

Comment: (FWIW my thinking would be that it'd be tricky to identify people across weddings like that, and you wouldn't want to bother unless you explicitly need it)

Answer (score 0):

I think these relationship works:

```
# wedding.rb
has_many :attendees
has_one :reception

# attendee.rb
belongs_to :wedding
belongs_to :reception

# reception.rb
belongs_to :wedding
has_many :attendees
```